# How to update/ upgrade angular cdk

Tags: angular, npm

I am a noob in angular and cant understand why **update** is erroring ?

**Objective** : Update version of cdk and material , and then install file-saver

**Command** : npm update @angular/cdk

**How to update my angular cdk?**

My package.json

> "@angular/animations": "~13.3.11",
> **"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",**
> "@angular/common": "~13.3.11",
> "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.11",
> "@angular/core": "~13.3.11",
> "@angular/material": "^10.2.7", ...

Error:

```
 # npm resolution error report

2023-03-28T18:16:59.106Z

While resolving: wiseui@1.0.0
Found: @angular/common@13.3.12
node_modules/@angular/common
  @angular/common@"~13.3.11" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
node_modules/@angular/cdk
  @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "version": "13.3.12",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "wiseui",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "path": "C:\\gegration\\main\\wiseui"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/common",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@angular/common",
        "spec": "~13.3.11",
        "from": {
          "location": "C:\\gion\\main\\wiseui"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "~13.3.11",
    "from": {
      "location": "C:\\....on\\main\\wiseui"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@angular/cdk",
      "version": "10.2.7",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "wiseui",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "path": "C:\\gooation\\main\\wiseui"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@angular/cdk",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@angular/cdk",
          "spec": "^10.2.7",
          "from": {
            "location": "C:\\goion\\main\\wiseui"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Error when installing file-saver, because this is what I want mainly

```
npm install file-saver --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.3.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=12.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@12.0.0-beta.34
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
npm ERR!     @angular/flex-layout@"^12.0.0-beta.34" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"13.3.12" from @angular/forms@13.3.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!     @angular/forms@"~13.3.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   peer @angular/cdk@"10.2.7" from @angular/material@10.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!     @angular/material@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See ....-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run `ng update @angular/common @angular/core @angular/material`? You need to modify your `package.json` the `@angular/material` version must be set to `~13.1.1`. Then run `npm update`

Comment: Also post your current `package.json` pls

Comment: `npm install` reads your `package-lock.json` and installs these versions. `npm update` reads the `package.json`, fetches the new versions from the registry, updates the `package-lock.json` based on the restrictions specified in the `package.json`, and installs these new versions. `ng update` is provided to actually bridge this gap you mention: ie it updates your `package.json` to use the newest angular versions, and runs `npm update`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to edit the question, but see no attachment option. I had a look at https://angular.io/guide/updating 
  @angular/cdk                       10.2.7 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/cdk@11
  @angular/cli                       13.3.10 -> 14.2.9        ng update @angular/cli@14
  @angular/core                      13.3.12 -> 14.3.0        ng update @angular/core@14
  @angular/material                  10.2.7 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/material@11
  @angular/youtube-player            12.2.0 -> 13.3.9         ng update @angular/youtube-player@13 , but errors

Comment: Added my package.json contents here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsyogr?file=package.json

Comment: Can anyone help please ? Is this a bug https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3666

Comment: Hi, just start with updating your `package.json` by setting all angular packages to `~13.1.1`, the run `npm update` and try again

Comment: why ~13.1.1 ?  I tried 13.3.11.   Was:  "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7", Now: "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.11",

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by trial and error

```
@angular/cdk
@angular/flex-layout
 @angular/forms
 @angular/compiler-cli
 @angular/localize
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
 @angular/flex-layout@
@angular/animations@
 @angular/material
@angular/router@
@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
 @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
 ng-circle-progress
karma-jasmine-html-reporter@
```

then

npm install file-saver --save

worked for me